# Unable to remove VS Code errors for React JSX

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Here is the error I get in VS Code:

```
'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

Everything is highlighted, and I am unable to autosave formatting fixes either.

[image: VSCode Error for JSX React]

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `import React from 'react'` on top of your file if not already added. The above issue generally comes when import is missed. If the issue still persists, try reopening the VS Code.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Also I have many other Next JS projects that don't require this.